# How to fit h2 to iPhone-sized devices

Tags: css

I've got this issue with h2 on iPhone-sized devices. The h2 goes off the center despite the code looks good. I can't figure out why it is happening.

[h2 off center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p42MR.png)

Here's my code:

```
/* for iPhone-sized devices */ @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
.container { width: auto }
body { padding: 0 }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 3em; text-align: left  }
h2 { font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 1.5em; text-align: center }
h3 { font-size: 1.8em }
h6 { font-size: 1em; text-align: left }
p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

My website is: [mamufka.com](http://www.mamufka.com).

Would love to hear some tips from you experienced guys!

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good to me, but if you want to make it horizontally aligned, you should remove the margins from the left and the right:

```
h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The text are actually bigger than the space you gave them because of that margin.

Comment: I've tried all of the advises but it still doesn't work. Could it be a case that mobile device doesn't read this part of CSS? I've tried to change the size of the font, and it wouldn't work as well. Maybe I messed something up with CSS? @gavin

Comment: @Anna Interesting. try `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` and try to change the color of the h2 to red, so you can be sure if it works or not. Also, try to change something in the desktop version, to see if the online website updates at all.

Comment: I've tried changing the color in the mobile part of the code and it doesn't read it, nothing changes. However in desktop version, all works just fine. Could there be some mistake I cannot see?

Answer (score 0):

You have a general rule on your `h2` element which is causing the margins to collide with the side before it aligns centrally.

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
h2 { font-size: 2em; margin: 0 0 1.5em 0; text-align: center }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove left/right margin from h2

```
h2 { font-size: 2em; margin: 0 0 1.5em; text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the margin in `@media` queries. Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
    h2 {
        margin: 2em 0em 0 0em;
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```